# ASP .NET Core 6 Web API - UPLOAD IMAGES

Tags: file-upload, asp.net-core-webapi

The `IFormFile` interface causes problems when I try to convert a string to an `IFormFile` with view model / Dto and get a status 400 with an error:

> The JSON value could not be converted to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile. Path: $.photo | LineNumber: 6 | BytePositionInLine: 19.

I know this error and I have come across it several times. The JSON does not know how to work with `IFormFile`.

And I do not know how solve the problem.

My model classes:

```
public class User
{
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; } = null!;
        public string Email { get; set; } = null!;
        public string UserName { get; set; } = null!;
        public byte[]? PasswordHash { get; set; } = null!;
        public byte[]? PasswordSalt { get; set; } = null!;
        public string PhotoUrl { get; set; } = null!;
}

[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int Id { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Full Name is a required field")]
public string FullName { get; set; } = null!;
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Email Name is a required field"), EmailAddress]
public string Email { get; set; } = null!;
[Required(ErrorMessage = "User Name is a required field")]
public string UserName { get; set; } = null!;
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is a required field")]
public string Password { get; set; } = null!;
public IFormFile? Photo { get; set; }
```

Controller:

```
private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;
private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _environment;

public RegisterController(IUserRepository userRepository, IWebHostEnvironment environment)
{
    _userRepository = userRepository;
    _environment = environment;
}

[HttpPost("signUp")]
public async Task<ActionResult<User>> SignUp([FromBody]UserViewModel model)
{
    string uniqueFileName = UploadedFile(model);

    if (await _userRepository.UserExists(model.UserName))
        return BadRequest("UserName Is Already Taken");

    var hmac = new HMACSHA512();
    var user = new User
            {
                UserName = model.UserName,
                PasswordHash = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(model.Password)),
                PasswordSalt = hmac.Key,
                Email = model.Email,
                FullName = model.FullName,
                PhotoUrl = uniqueFileName
            };

     await _userRepository.AddUser(user);

     return user;
}

private string UploadedFile(UserViewModel model)
{
    string uniqueFileName = null!;

    if (model.Photo != null)
    {
        string uploadsFolder = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "Images");
        uniqueFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + model.Photo.FileName;
        string filePath = Path.Combine(uploadsFolder, uniqueFileName);

        using var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
        model.Photo.CopyTo(fileStream);
    }

    return uniqueFileName;
}
```

Comment: replace this [FromBody] with [FromForm]

Comment: @CodingMytra If I use [FromForm], I can't use Swagger to add, but in the Angular UI I can't add a new user, it gives me bugs

Comment: what error you get when using swagger?

Comment: @CodingMytra I did as you told me and I used [FromForm] and on the server side I see that it works but if in Angular in the registration form I try to create a new user then it shows me the holding errors and I can't add I think it's better for us to talk in a private chat

Comment: you will be need to make required changes in angular side also to make it work.

Comment: I don't know what I will have to change there
I sat on it for an hour and did not understand that the URL remained the same URL
 @CodingMytra

Comment: URL is not changed but the content type is changed. you need to create FormData and add the file to it and then call API. check this [article](https://arminzia.com/blog/file-upload-with-aspnet-core-and-angular/) for refrence.

Comment: HI @OpalDavid, it is better for you to share the angular code.Besides,what's wrong with swagger if you change to [FromForm]. More explanation with picture and code would  be helpful.